# Extract amount between two values

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have two oracle tables.

Table A

| Amount |
| --- |
| 200 |
| 500 |
| 100 |

Table B

| Amount From | Amount To | Approver |
| --- | --- | --- |
| -100 | 499 | Approver1 |
| -499 | 1000 | Approver2 |
| -50 | 300 | Approver3 |

I am expecting that if Oracle SQL returns
value 200 from table A then it should fetch First row from the table 2 ( -100 and 499)
,value 500 from table A then it should fetch second row from the table 2 (-499 and 1000)
,value 100 from table A then it should fetch third row from the table 2 (-50 and 199).

if amount falls between amount_from & amount_to which is least then i need to find correspond approver.

Comment: Do you have any keys for joining the rows? "Order in table" isn't a good one "In Oracle, a table stores its rows in unspecified order regardless of the order which rows were inserted into the database"

Comment: But, COLUMN A = 200 from the 1st table is between **every** two values in table B, so why should only 1st row be fetched from table B in that case? Similarly, COLUMN A = 100 represents the same case. I guess you should explain what you meant.

Comment: _First row_ - according to what? Does the table also have an id or timestamp column, or similar?

Comment: Is it on purpose that the three ranges overlap? -499 to 1000 contains -100 to 499 and this range again contains -50 to 300. You may be looking for the smallest range an A amount exists in, or the range where the from-amount is closest to the value, or the range where the to-amount is closest to the value, or ... Please explain thoroughly by what rule to pick the range.

Answer (score 1):

From Oracle 12, you can use a `LATERAL` join and return the first matched row.

```sql
SELECT a.amount,
       b.approver
FROM   table_a a
       LEFT OUTER JOIN LATERAL (
         SELECT approver
         FROM   table_b b
         WHERE  a.amount BETWEEN b.amount_from AND b.amount_to
         ORDER BY
                amount_to - amount_from, -- Smallest range
                approver
         FETCH FIRST ROW ONLY
       ) b
       ON 1 = 1 -- Join condition is in the lateral query.
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_a (Amount) AS
SELECT 200 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 500 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 100 FROM DUAL;

CREATE TABLE table_b (Amount_From, Amount_To, Approver) AS
SELECT -100,  499, 'Approver1' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT -499, 1000, 'Approver2' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT  -50,  300, 'Approver3' FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

| AMOUNT | APPROVER |
| --- | --- |
| 200 | Approver3 |
| 500 | Approver2 |
| 100 | Approver3 |

> I am expecting that if Oracle SQL returns value 200 from table A then it should fetch First row from the table 2 ( -100 and 499) ,value 500 from table A then it should fetch second row from the table 2 (-499 and 1000) ,value 100 from table A then it should fetch third row from the table 2 (-50 and 199).

In SQL (in any dialect, not just Oracle's SQL dialect) there is no concept of a "first" or "second" row unless you specify an `ORDER BY` clause and can define a deterministic ordering of the results set.

In this case, you stated that you wanted:

> If amount falls between `amount_from` & `amount_to` which is least then I need to find correspond approver.

and the "least" could be the lowest `amount_from` or the lowest `amount_to` or the smallest range between `amount_from` and `amount_to`; I opted for the last metric, the range, but you can equally implement any of the other metrics to determine what is the "least".

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/VfmyFL9-)

Answer (score 0):

```
with tb as (
  select a.col_a, b.amount_from, b.amount_to, 
    row_number() over(partition by a.col_a order by b.amount_to) rn
  from tab_a a
  left join tab_b b on a.column_a between b.amount_from and b.amount_to 
)
select col_a, amount_from, amount_to
from tb
where rn=1;
```

Having strictly your "requirements", I'd do something like the above. Still, like the colleagues have mentions, this is a most unusual database design. A table should have a primary key. And, eventually, foreign keys. I do not see any primary key for table_b. And the amount intervals look quite strange because they intersect each other - something I haven't seen anywhere... Usually those intervals do not intersect.

Answer (score 0):

One of the options is to use analytic function Min() Over() to establish table join:

```sql
WITH        -- Sample data
    tbl_a (AMOUNT) AS
        (
            SELECT 200 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
            SELECT 500 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
            SELECT 100 FROM DUAL
        ),
    tbl_b (AMOUNT_FROM, AMOUNT_TO, APPROVER) AS
        (
            SELECT -100,  499, 'Approver1' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
            SELECT -499, 1000, 'Approver2' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
            SELECT  -50,  300, 'Approver3' FROM DUAL
        )
--  
--  Main SQL
SELECT AMOUNT, APPROVER 
FROM (   Select      a.AMOUNT,
                    Min(CASE  WHEN a.AMOUNT Between b.AMOUNT_FROM And b.AMOUNT_TO 
                              THEN b.AMOUNT_TO END) OVER(Partition By a.AMOUNT) "MIN_TO",
                    b.AMOUNT_FROM, b.AMOUNT_TO, b.APPROVER
        From        tbl_b b  
        Inner Join  tbl_a a ON( 1 = 1 )
     )
WHERE AMOUNT_TO = MIN_TO
--  
--  R e s u l t :
    AMOUNT APPROVER 
---------- ---------
       100 Approver3
       200 Approver3
       500 Approver2
```